# Invoking Rest API in @preDestory method and getting unknownHostExeception issue in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm calling API using RestTeplate.postForEntity(); in the @preDestroy annotated method. Deploying it as AWS EKS and using kubectl command scaling down the pod and the @preDestroy method is getting called but RestTeplate.postForEntity() call is failing due to unknownhostExeception

Error log: 
Test API call is failed org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://test.com/v2/testprocess/test": test.com; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: test.com|    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:742)|    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:689)|  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:452)|    at com.test.TestClient.testAPI(c.java:226)| at com.test.TestClient.testAPI(TestClient.java:52)|Caused by: **java.net.UnknownHostException: test.com|    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)|  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)|   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)|   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)**|  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)| at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)|   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)|   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)|  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)|  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)| at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)|  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)|   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)|    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)|    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)|    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)|  at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)|    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:733)|    ... 4 more

@mozello -  thanks for responding,  In my app I call the API in two aspect, 1. During the App startup for this i'm using  @postConstuctor annotated method and API is call is happening perfectly fine. which means the k8's able to resolve the "test.com" right.
But getting this unknownHostException issue only during the @preDestroy method execution, pls suggest.

Comment: Hi Sivakumar Neelam Veera! First, check if your target domain name resolves properly within a k8s cluster. Check [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/), please.

Comment: I see you added info to the question. Check this link - [terminating with grace](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace). Maybe PreStop Hook can help.

Comment: Can you post your deployment spec? Also, can you elaborate more about this `test.com`, eg. is this an external service or a service running in the same cluster?

Comment: Sivakumar Neelam Veera, any updates?